# Jquery UI autocomplete not displaying results

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I know the question title seems like a duplicate, but I've been unable to find an answer to this question.

I'm using Jquery UI's autocomplete, and I can see the proper JSON data coming back in my debugger.  However, nothing's coming back to the textbox.

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        myAutoComplete("#<%= myTxtBox.ClientID %>", "AutoCompletePage.aspx");
    });

    function myAutoComplete(ObjectId, DataURL) {
        $(ObjectId).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: DataURL, dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: { q: request.term, limit: 10 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item[1], value: item[0], id: item[0]}
                        }))
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

a snippet from my AutoCompletePage.aspx page:

```
foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
{
    string[] cells = new string[] { dataRow[0].ToString(), dataRow[1].ToString() };
    output.Add(cells);
}
```

And later...

```
Response.Write(json.Serialize(output));
```

You can see in this picture that JSON data *is* being returned, but nothing's happening to my textbox.  Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

[image: autocomplete results]

Comment: What about the definition of `myTxtBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a hunch you should not be using `jsonp` here. JSONP is generally used for cross-domain requests.

It appears that you are making a request in the same domain (additionally, the data coming back may not have a callback function to call), so you should be fine just using normal `json`.

Try changing your `datatype` parameter to `json`:

```
    $(ObjectId).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({ url: DataURL, dataType: 'json',
                data: { q: request.term, limit: 10 },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item[1], value: item[0], id: item[0]}
                    }))
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: Wow.  I've tried so many variations with and without json/jsonp (also trying type: POST), but this one works.  Thanks for simple answer.  I was using jsonp because it's used in the example on jqueryui's website, but I guess it's because they are pulling data from a different domain.  Thanks again.